# ruby: return true or false based on condition inside method

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I created following method to return true or false

```
def method
  total_value = some_value
  item_value = item_value
  return true if total_value < item_value
end
```

I tried to put return true but only works when its true.

It returns true if `total_value < item_value` but returns null if its not true.

I also tried with if else and it works but is this the best way?

```
def method
   total_value = some_value
   item_value = item_value
  if total_value < item_value
    true
  else
    false
  end
end
```

Comment: Note `method` is an existing method, you are (probably unwillingly) overriding it.

Comment: FYI, when you write a method, even though it's just a sample method to add the question. You should try to write it correctly. Both methods above would have `undefined` error. Look at your code again, you will know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
def method_name
  total_value < item_value
end
```

Ruby will always return the value of the last evaluated statement in the function.

Comment: Thanks you so much